# Freezing exports with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I assume this is the best way to do it:

```
export const stdMarker = '@json-stdio';
export const stdEventName = '@json-stdio-event';

Object.defineProperties(module.exports, {
  'stdMarker': {
     writable: false
   },
  'stdEventName': {
     writable: false
  }
});
```

is there any sort of shorthand for this? It would be interesting if TS offered something like:

```
export frozen const stdMarker = '@json-stdio';
export frozen const stdEventName = '@json-stdio-event';
```

or whatever. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

Comment: ES module exports are already read-only by specs. They are writable only because they fall back to CJS on compilation. The 'best' way to do this is to use native modules when they are ready, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18442 . Why would you need that any way? Descriptors can affect the way module exports can be spied or stubbed in tests.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've defined `stdMarker` and `stdEventName` as `const` (and their value is a primitive, not an object) you should have the desired behavior out of the box.
When importing the const in another file, and attempting to modify it, I get an error:

```
Cannot assign to 'test' because it is not a variable.
```

What behavior do you expect from a frozen export? Your defineProperties call is doing a similar thing to `const` in this situation.